# Distro Redmine Ubuntu 20.04LTS not installing any plugins?

Tags: 20.04, plugins, redmine

I am wondering, if this is something wrong with my installation, or should I report this to Ubuntu Redmine packagers.

I have an Ubuntu 20.04LTS system on which I installed redmine from Ubuntu distro:

```
apt install redmine redmine-pgsql
```

The installed version is redmine 4.0.6-2

The package works fine on its own, I can run redmine with mod_passenger.

However, whenever I try to install **any** plugin (from redmineUP, or other sources, checking for support for redmine 4.0), I:

1. get **NO** dependencies installed when executing b`undle install --without development test --no-deployment`
   -- just a message saying everything is fine.
2. get various missing dependancies related errors when execing `bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME={plugin} RAILS_ENV=production`

The only plugins work that are also packaged by distro: `apt-get install redmine-plugin-custom-css` works, but that is only a single plugin... about 2 are available, but no agile/kanban/etc.

As I started to dig in deeper, I noticed also that redmine is supposed to run under ruby2.6

However, Ubuntu releases don't have it: Ubuntu 18 used ruby2.3 and Ubuntu 20 uses ruby2.7 !

Has anyone been succcesful in using plugins with Ubuntu distro install of Redmine, or is this something I should report at Ubuntu distro?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for distro packaged Redmine you *can't use the default Redmine plugin installation procedure* which is described in Redmine page.

Instead you have to follow *distro* plugin installation procedure, which in Ubuntu case is noted in /usr/share/doc/redmine/README.Debian.gz and which is:

> You can manually install plugins by dropping them in the
> `/usr/share/redmine/plugins/` directory (all files must be readable by
> the `www-data` user), and running the redmine setup again:
>
> `dpkg-reconfigure --default-priority redmine`

**However**, README says you should actually use `--unseen-only` switch. Which you **MUST NOT DO**, else it will *silently delete all your existing configurations* (eg. LDAP authentication sources), users and passwords and will reset Redmine to initial config with single admin user.

Instead, during running `dpkg-reconfigure` you must choose **No** when asked to reset database. This will then configure plugin and leave your existing config alone.